# A linear mapping that is always positive is zero?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let us consider a continuous linear mapping $L : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $n\geq2$.

Is the fact that $L \geq 0$ implies that $L$ is equal to zero ?

My idea : Since $L\geq 0$ this means that for all $x=(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ one has $$L(x_1,...,x_n) \geq 0,$$
But taking $y=-x$ then we get that
$$ Ly \leq 0$$

Comment: Your idea is correct.

Comment: Note that the range of $L$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. Since $L$ is non-negative the range cannot be all of $\mathbb{R}$. The only other linear subspace is $\{0\}$.

Comment: @jakobdt Thank you, but in this case we don't have the equivalence between $L\geq 0$ and $L=0$ ?

Comment: You do not need to assume continuity. It follows from linearity.

Comment: @hanava331 I'm not sure I understand your question. My point is that the range $L(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is equal to either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\{0\}$ because these are the only linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$. If $L\geq0$ then $L(\mathbb{R})\subseteq[0,\infty)$ which leaves $\{0\}$ as the only possible range of $L$. Hence, $L=0$.